# Samsung TV App cant connect to server

Tags: apache2, samsung-smart-tv

I have just begun developing with the Samsung SDK. I am creating some test applications. I created an app which simply redirects to my apache2 server `window.location.href="http://10.42.243.15 "` When I launch the App it hangs on the loading screen. I can access my server from the browser app and I can also use an app to redirect to google with no issues. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
Ok with some testing I have found that using an iFrame I can access my server. This is a workaround but I am still curious as to the original issue. Is there some issue with Samsung Apps and http on a LAN?
Thanks again

Comment: is this browser loading screen or your app loading screen? Is there any log messages in apache access log from your TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung may block the window.location.href function on their browser for samsung apps. Please look at their developer site which telling us not to do that method and it's violating their application policy: "Dynamic loading app is not permitted"

http://samsungdforum.com/Support/SmartTVapppolicies

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there some issue with Samsung Apps and http on a LAN?

There is definitely no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

It may be 2 reasons:

1. Is your application call [sendReadyWidget](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00006/common_module_widget_object.html#ref00006-common-module-widget-object-sendreadyevent) on start?
2. Is network 10.42.243.15 accessible from TV? What is your TV`s IP?